# How to have the list of table in a monetdb database?

Tags: monetdb

In postgresql, one can have all tables names by running the following query

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public';
```

Is there something similar in monetdb to have the list of tables ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally find this query

```
select tables.name from tables where tables.system=false ;
```

Answer (score 12):

If you are using mclient, in the command line you could simply use the command "\d" to list all the tables in the current database.

```
sql> \d

TABLE  sys.table1 

TABLE  sys.table2

TABLE  sys.table3
```

Additionally, use the command "\d tablename" to view the metadata of a table - equivalent to "show create table" in mysql.