# How to show available tables in monetdb using python api?

Tags: python, monetdb

When using mclient it is possible to list all tables in database by issuing command '\d'. I'm using python-monetdb package and I don't know how the same can be accomplished. I've seen example like "SELECT * FROM TABLES;" but I get an error that "tables" table does not exist.

Comment: This thread can be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23007549/how-to-have-the-list-of-table-in-a-monetdb-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you need to specify that you are looking for the `tables` table that belongs to the default `sys` schema, or `sys.tables`. The SQL query that returns the names of all non-system tables in MonetDB is:

`SELECT t.name FROM sys.tables t WHERE t.system=false`

In Python this should look something like:

```
import monetdb.sql

connection = monetdb.sql.connect(username='<username>', password='<password>', hostname='<hostname>', port=50000, database='<database>')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT t.name FROM sys.tables t WHERE t.system=false')
```

If you are looking for tables only in a specific schema, you will need to extend your query, specifying the schema:

`SELECT t.name FROM sys.tables t WHERE t.system=false AND t.schema_id IN (SELECT s.id FROM sys.schemas s WHERE name = '<schema-name>')`

where the `<schema-name>` is your schema, surrounded by single quotes.